# How to forward all subdirectory to index

Tags: .htaccess

I was having many sub directories which is fetched by google, I want to forward Permanently if the request from any directory it has to forward to main domain.

Like::

```
From: www.domain.com/help/software/desktop/index.php
To: www.domain.com
```

My complete htaccess file is

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^cosa/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+/.+\.php$ /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/.+\.php$ /
```

To redirect all subfolders, try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+/.+(\.php)?$ /
```

Comment: Will this redirect only three folders or all folders ??

Comment: Its not redrirecting for multiple folders. May be the style sheet is missing. I can see the website without styles.

Comment: What url did you try?

Comment: I just put something normal which not exist like www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/index

Comment: The second Redirect is working fine for multiple subfolders , I just tested it on my apache server, do you have any other rules there in your htaccess file?

Comment: Please post your complete .htaccess file in your question

Comment: To solve your style sheet , add **<base href="/">** inbetween <head> and </head> of your webpage. 

like this :


<head>
<base href="/"> </head>

Comment: i submitted. the complete htaccess file

Comment: Now its wroking perfect. thanks for your advice.. Its help me.. take care.

Comment: Yes, its only for a url ending with .php, do you want more  extensions to match the pattern ?

Comment: Yes, and also if there is no extension ? could u send me.. thanks.

Comment: i have the .php optional in regex pattern, now it will accept urls with or without .php .